# Deleting a database record using $_POST with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, uri

I've been doing it all wrong, I used to take the value from the URI segment and didn't realize it wasn't the ideal way. So I changed my approach and now have everything via a $_POST. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, could someone shed some light? My view contains tabular data listing items pulled from the DB. Each item has two links, "View" and "Delete." The code seems to work but was wondering if it could be coded better. I forgot that the form name wasn't unique, so when I went to go delete a record, it would always delete the newest record (the last hidden field was set).

**myview.php** (snippet)

```
<?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
    <form method="POST" name="myform<?php echo $location->id;?>" action="/location/delete">
    <a href="/location/view/<?php echo $location->id;?>">View</a> <a href="#" onclick="document.myform<?php echo $location->id;?>.submit();">Delete</a>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="<?php echo $location->id;?>">
    </form>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `I've been doing it all wrong,` - says who? Providing your app is controlled, deleting via the URI segment is a perfectly viable solution. Also your code uses `$records as $record` but you refer to it as `$location` - doesn't sit right

Comment: and I would use absolute URLs using the `base_url()` method to avoid future issue (moving the project to sub-folder..etc)

Comment: Why not little bit ajaxify your app and make a async post request to delete record? That way you will not have to use multiple forms at all.

Comment: Sorry, my bad yea I modified the code prior to posting and it should be `$record->id`.  I plan on using Ajax but I can't depend on that in case someone gets around to disabling JS. I don't want users to be able to delete records via a URL (eg http://domain.com/items/delete/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this later, here's how I solved my issue.

In my controller I have a method called `delete` that checks to see if the form field was submitted via a `$_POST`. If there's no variable, redirect them somewhere with an error message.  If the field was passed, then go through the normal checks to make sure the record can be deleted.

```
if(!isset($_POST['item_id']))
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'item cannot be removed!'); 
    redirect("/item");
}


if($this->input->post('item_id')) {         
    ... code ....
    ... code ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Viewing/Deleting via uri id is perfectly fine, I wouldn't venture to say that using `$_POST` is wrong, but creating a new unique form for every delete element is terribly messy, and weighed against what you are gaining (no exposed id i guess?), I believe it is more 'correct' to use the uri for delete functions.

If you only want certain people to be able to delete certain records, handle that programmatically in the delete function itself, don't depend on the fact that the request is only sent via `$_POST`.  This is not dependable, anyone can generate a post request.

Comment: Yea, I have checks in place to make sure the record they are attemping to delete does belong to them. I saw references in regards to cross site attacks and what not. The biggest issue would be someone who passes a URL that contains the record id (if they happen to know it), and the person not knowingly would click on it and boom, bye bye record.

Comment: so the situation you are trying to prevent, is someone finding out the record id, and the user it belongs to, creating a link on another site, tricking that specific user that it belongs to, to click the link...  : |      I think it'd probably be easier to get the user at gun point and make them go in and delete it themselves. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is with this line:

```
<?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
         <form method="POST" name="myform<?php echo $location->id;?>"      action="/location/delete">
         <a href="/location/view/<?php echo $location->id;?>">View</a> <a href="#" onclick="document.myform<?php echo
 $location->id;?>.submit();">Delete</a>
         <br />
          <input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="<?php echo $location->id;?>">
         </form>
      <?php endforeach ?>
```

You can not do looping for a form. Instead, use the following code:

```
   <form method="POST" name="myform<?php echo $location->id;?>" action="/location/delete">
<?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
    a href="/location/view/<?php echo $location->id;?>">View</a> <a href="#" onclick="document.myform<?php echo $location->id;?>.submit();">Delete</a>
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="<?php echo $location->id;?>">
    <?php endforeach ?>
       </form>
```